Problems to create a parameterized TypeScript 5 method decorator mapping arguments
I would like to create a TypeScript 5 method decorator with parameters, for logging purpose.
A parameter mappers could allow to map initial function arguments to arbitrary values.
My first difficult was to create a type from method arguments.
I found this great article (note: outdated because it was written before variadic tuples existed)
and ended up with a working version (at least I assumed it worked).
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...any[]] ? T[0] : never;
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => any) extends (_: any, ...tail: infer TT) => any ? TT : [];
type Length<T extends any[]> = T['length'];
type IsRest<T, P extends any[]> = Required<T> extends never ? number extends Length<P> ? true : false : false;

type ParamsToFunc<T extends any[], R = any, RT extends any[] = Required<T>> = [
    ...(
        IsRest<Head<T>, T> extends true
        ? [(...v: T) => R]
        : Head<T> extends never
            ? Head<RT> extends never
                ? []
                : [(v?: Head<RT>) => R]
            : [(v: Head<T>) => R]
    ),
    ...(
        IsRest<Head<T>, T> extends true
            ? []
            : Length<Tail<T>> extends 0
                ? []
                : ParamsToFunc<Tail<T>, R>
    ),
];

Here are tests
type T01 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<() => string>>;
// []

type T02 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: string) => string[]>>;
// [(v: string) => any]

type T03 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: string[]) => number>>;
// [(v: string[]) => any]

type T04 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: undefined, b: string[]) => number>>;
// [(v: undefined) => any, (v: string[]) => any]

type T05 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: undefined, ...rest: string[]) => number>>;
// [(v: undefined) => any, (...v: string[]) => any]

type T06 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(...rest: string[]) => number>>;
// [(...v: string[]) => any]

type T07 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: string[], ...rest: string[]) => number>>;
// [(v: string[]) => any, (...v: string[]) => any]

type T08 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: string, b: number) => number>>;
//  [(v: string) => any, (v: number) => any]

type T09 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: string, b: number, ...rest: string[]) => number>>;
// [(v: string) => any, (v: number) => any, (...v: string[]) => any]

type T10 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(options?: boolean) => Promise<number>>>;
// [(v?: boolean | undefined) => any]

type T11 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(options?: boolean, other?: boolean) => Promise<number>>>;
// [(v?: boolean | undefined) => any, (v?: boolean | undefined) => any]

type T12 = ParamsToFunc<Parameters<(a: string | number, to: string, options?: boolean) => Promise<number>>>;
// [(v: string | number) => any, (v: string) => any, (v?: boolean | undefined) => any]

So far so good. The type handles tricky cases like optional parameters or rest parameters.
Now, here is a simplified version of my method decorator factory (making it useless).
type TypedFunction<This, Args extends any[], Return> = (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return;
type LoggedMethodOptions<Args extends any[]> = { mappers: ParamsToFunc<Args> };

function loggedMethod<This, Args extends any[], Return>(_options?: LoggedMethodOptions<Args>) {
    return function (
        target: TypedFunction<This, Args, Return>,
        _context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, TypedFunction<This, Args, Return>>
    ) {
        return function (this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
            return target.call(this, ...args);
        };
    };
}

After spending time to create a proper type I expected things to be OK but I was wrong.
type FileId = string;
class FileService {
    // OK
    @loggedMethod({ mappers: [v => v.toUpperCase()] })
    deleteFile(_id: FileId): void {}

    // error "Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)" for all mappers
    // however I see
    // (property) mappers: [(v: string) => any, (v: string) => any, (v?: { verbose?: boolean; } | undefined) => any]
    @loggedMethod({ mappers: [v => v.toUpperCase(), v => v.toUpperCase(), v => v?.verbose] })
    copyFile(_from: FileId, _to: FileId, _options?: { verbose?: boolean }): void { }

    // OK (makes me sick because `copyFile` seems so close)
    @loggedMethod({ mappers: [v => v.toUpperCase(), v => v.toUpperCase(), v => v.toUpperCase()] })
    copyFile2(_from: FileId, _to: FileId, _3rdParty: FileId): void { }
    
    // error "Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)" for all mappers
    // however I see
    // property) mappers: [(v: string) => any, (v: any[]) => any]
    @loggedMethod({ mappers: [v => v.toUpperCase(), v => v.length] })
    saveToFile(_to: FileId, _contents: any[]): void { }

    // OK
    @loggedMethod({ mappers: [v => v.toUpperCase()] })
    getFileAndMetadata(_desc: FileId): void { }
}

It seems that TypeScript considers the mapper input is of type any as soon as there are initial argument with different types.
So, copyFile has errors (FileId + FileId + other) while copyFile2 has none (FileId + FileId + FileId). Still, the type shown for mappers seems correct.
Here is a TypeScript Playground with all the code above (TypeScript 5.6.3 / target ES2022).
I don't understand why types seem OK when I hover the mouse over the definition and at the same time TypeScript complains.

could you help me to understand why there is such difference?
could you help me to write a better version (of the type, or of the decorator, or of both, I don't know) DONE, thanks to @jcalz


Welcome to Stack Overflow. • I don't see a single mapped type anywhere in this question or the code. Could you please [edit] to not use that terminology? • The article you reference was written before variadic tuples existed so you're writing some things in an unnecessarily roundabout way; it seems like at least some of this code should be simplified before you should ask questions about it, so we can work with a [mre].

(see prev comment) I'm trying to slog through this to understand what you're doing. What does "makes me sick" refer to in your comments?

(please see prev comments). So, it's hard to see what you're missing because decorator functions infer from their return types, and presumably your type is complicated enough that contextual typing fails. If I try to rewrite your type so I understand it I get this version which works. I'd be happy to write that up if your question is "how should I write this" and not "what specific thing goes wrong with my version", which is harder (for me anyway) to answer. How would you like to proceed?

Thank your very much for your time and your working example.

I don't understand your point about about the mapped type because I think ParamsToFunc is a mapped type. However I'll take a closer look at variadic tuples and at your fixed version of ParamsToFunc.
"makes me sick" was because copyFile and copyFile2 seemed so close, yet the decorator wouldn't work with copyFile.
you're right, I asked because I needed help to write a better and simpler version. However, I'm also interested in learning what caused the problem.


I'm very confused because when I hover the mouse over the params attribute it shows something correct, but at the same time TypeScript complains about the mapper argument being "any", but not always.

I just added methods withValueAndRest and withRest (and updated the playground) because these cases confuse me too. There is still this gap between definitions when I hover the mouse and the ones TypeScript complains about. @jcalz your version doesn't solve them either. Maybe rest parameters are too much for TypeScript to handle?

• "I think ParamsToFunc is a mapped type". I linked to the mapped types docs. They are {[P in K]: ⋯}; I don't see in anywhere in your code, so there are no mapped types here. What makes you think it's a mapped type? • Why are you writing v => v.map? That makes no sense because v is a string | undefined or something; maybe you mean (...v) => v.map? At this point it feels like you're moving the goal or asking a followup question about how rest parameters work. • Could you [edit] and fix these issues so we can proceed?

You're right, so I removed mentions to mapped types. I updated the question with your solution. Thanks again. It seems I've wasted enough of your time.

No, I'm happy to spend time here, but I am confused about why my solution got added to the question. Now I can't write an answer with it? Or you're saying now that I've provided a working version then you really just want to understand what's wrong with your original version and you no longer want a solution? Feels like moving the goal again. Would you mind [edit]ing this to ask for a working version and I can add my solution as an answer, and if you really need your more complex version to be explained you can open a new question for it?  Or how would you like to proceed here?

I added your solution so that other people can see a working version, but feel free to write an answer and I'll edit again if necessary. Is it a bad practice to add a working version? I'm new so I don't know yet. I don't think the goal moved because I asked what was wrong from the beginning, but for clarity I could open a new question and refer to this one.

All right, I've done what I can with my answer. I'd appreciate it if you remove my code from your question when you get a chance.

In trying to understand what your ParamsToFunc<T> does, I worked on writing my own more "direct" version (whether or not it's actually more direct is debatable; mine doesn't define extra utility types):
type ParamsToFunc<T extends any[], A extends any[] = []> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? ParamsToFunc<R, [...A, (v: F) => any]> :
    T extends [] ? A :
    T extends [(infer F)?, ...infer R] ? (
        T extends R ? [...A, (...v: T) => any] : ParamsToFunc<R, [...A, (v?: F) => any]>
    ) : never;

This version works without errors. It reproduces the test cases, and the contextual type of callback parameters in things like
@loggedMethod({ mappers: [v => v.toUpperCase(), v => v.toUpperCase(), v => v.toUpperCase()] })
copyFile2(_from: FileId, _to: FileId, _3rdParty: FileId): void { }

happens properly; no "implicit any" errors.
I'll briefly describe how my version of ParamsToFunc, I first check T extends [infer F, ...infer R] to see if it is a tuple with a required first element; if so, we recurse and add the "plain" function to the accumulator A. Otherwise I check T extends [] to see if we've hit the end of the tuple; if so, we return the accumulator A.  Otherwise, I check T extends [(infer F)?, ...infer R] to see if the tuple has an optional element. This will effectively be true no matter what; so the next check is T extends R to see if the rest of the array and the current array are the same. If so, then we have hit a plain array or a rest element, since pulling the first element off the array doesn't change it.  If we've hit that rest element then we return the accumulator with the "rest" function at the end. Otherwise we recurse and add the "optional" function to the accumulator A. Then we've hit the impossible case where T extends [(infer F)?, ...infer R] is false, so we return never.
So this version works, but it doesn't necessarily answer why your version doesn't.

Going back to your definition, the minimum change I can make to it which causes it to work is:
type ParamsToFunc<T extends any[], R = any, RT extends any[] = Required<T>> =
    IsRest<Head<T>, T> extends true ? [(...v: T) => R] :
    [...(
        Head<T> extends never ? (
            Head<RT> extends never ? [] : [(v?: Head<RT>) => R]
        ) : [(v: Head<T>) => R]
    ), ...(
        Length<Tail<T>> extends 0 ? [] : ParamsToFunc<Tail<T>, R>
    )];

I've moved your IsRest<Head<T>, T> tests out of the pair of variadic tuple pieces, combined them into a single test, and put it first.  The rest of your code is essentially the same.
And again, the test cases are the same but now the callback parameters are always contextually typed.
This still doesn't answer why your version doesn't work, but it shows the location of the problem.

At this point you have two working versions but no definitive answer for why the other one didn't work. My guess is that, since decorators have to infer their generic type arguments contextually from the expected return type of the function, the order of inference can be different depending on the types involved. Your original version always uses variadic tuples, even for the nonrecursive/base case. The updated version does not. Why this should matter is unclear to me.
There are GitHub issues about similar problems, like microsoft/TypeScript#52047, but I can't be positive it's the same underlying situation. That one is considered a bug in TypeScript, but one that might not be trivial to fix.
So there you go. If this question is "how can I make it work", I've answered it. If it's primarily "why doesn't this work", then I've only posted guesswork, and you might need to file a GitHub issue to know for sure (but if you do this, I'd strongly recommend paring down the code to the absolute minimum which demonstrates the problem).
Playground link to code

Thank your for your time and your answer. I've read the GitHub issue and it seems a deep understanding of TypeScript internals would be needed to understand the problem, maybe I'll try to go further, maybe not. It was a good idea not to use variadic tuples in some cases.
